# One-loop 1PI effective action and dressed propagators

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, propagator, 1pi-effective-action

I'm working through the notes of [https://www.hef.ru.nl/~kleiss/qft.pdf](https://www.hef.ru.nl/%7Ekleiss/qft.pdf)

and I'm currently on page 46: Computing the 1PI effective action and I'm having a lot of problems with the language.

> We start by considering a general one-loop 1PI diagram such as that of Eq.(1.86), and cutting through the loop at some arbitrary place. We then have a propagator `dressed' with zero or more vertices where external lines are` radiated off'. The diagram in question is
>
> [image]

If I cut through this loop arbitrarily, I'll end up without a loop at all. And if we’re talking about 1PI diagrams, why am I destroying a 1PI diagram by cutting through it? I'll assume I end up with a straight line that has external lines "radiating off". But then how does the next sentence make any sense at all

> If there are precisely $n$ external lines we can denote this by
>
> [image]

why are we using a graphic that has a loop if we supposedly just sliced through our loop? I'm very confused... any elucidation would be most helpful

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/414617/2451

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP has a point: Since Ref. 1 here cuts the loop open in 1-loop 1PI-diagrams, the result, OP's cross-hatched$^1$ diagram therefore consists of 0-loop/tree diagrams. This is confirmed by comparing with the latter eqs. (1.93-96).

References:

1. R. Kleiss, [*Pictures, Paths, Particles, Processes, Feynman Diagrams and All That and the Standard Model*](https://www.hef.ru.nl/%7Ekleiss/qft.pdf), lecture notes, 2013; section 1.5.3.

--

$^1$ Confusingly, 1PI diagrams are denoted by a slightly different cross-hatching on the bottom of p. 46.