What are exactly the loop correction to the potential?
I am struggling with the concept of quantum effective action, but first recall the definition : given a Wilsonian effective action $W[J]$ of our theory, the quantum effective action is just
$$\Gamma[\phi_{J}]\equiv W[J]-\phi_{J}\cdot J\tag{1}$$
where the dot notation is used to indicate an integral over $d^{4}x$, and I have denoted with
$$\phi_{J}(x)\equiv<\phi>_{J}\equiv Z[J]^{-1}∫ \mathcal{D}\phi e^{-\frac{S[\phi]+J\cdot\phi}{\hbar}}\phi=\frac{δ W[J]}{δ J(x)}\tag{2}$$
the quantum average in presence of the external source $J$. If I understand correctly, $\Gamma[\phi_{J}]$ is just an object that, if somehow known, would let us to compute the partition function $\mathcal{Z}$ simply solving its equation of motion:
$$\frac{δ\Gamma}{δ\phi_{J}}\bigg|_{\phi_{J}=\phi_{c}}=0\iff\phi_{c}=\phi_{J=0}=<\phi>.\tag{3}$$
So plugging this "classical" solution into the quantum action gives
$$\mathcal{Z}[J]=e^{-\frac{1}{\hbar}W[J]}=e^{-\frac{1}{\hbar}(\Gamma[\phi_{J}]+J\cdot\phi_{J})}\Rightarrow \mathcal{Z}=∫ \mathcal{D}\phi e^{-\frac{S[\phi]}{\hbar}}=e^{-\frac{1}{\hbar}\Gamma[\phi_{c}]}.\tag{4}$$
which encodes the information about transition amplitudes. This shows how the quantum effective action "contains" all the quantum effects associated to the measure $\mathcal{D}\phi$. Here my questions:

Why is this relevant if we are not able to compute fully $\Gamma$? I mean, it's usually said that it helps because it enable us to correct the potential with loop contributions $$V_{eff}=V+V_{1-loop}+...,\tag{5}$$ but then what do we do with that? To me this seems not easier than just do the loop calculations in perturbation theory using just $S[\phi]$, could you please explain how to put this things down to Earth? I don't think I really understand what does it mean to correct a potential with loops.


Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/337898/2451, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/414617/2451 and links therein.

In eq. (4) is $\mathcal{Z}=\mathcal{Z}[J=0]$?

yes sorry but I see your are already fixing

How does $\mathcal{Z}=\mathcal{Z}[J=0]$ (which is essentially just a number; more precisely: a function of some coupling constants) depend on $\phi_c$ in eq. (4)?

Well I just put $J=0$ from the previous equation, I am not really sure about it I just wrote what I thought was possible... if this is not correct please let me know.

Ah, $\phi_{c}=\phi_{J=0}=<\phi>_{J=0}$ is essentially also just a number rather than a variable. It is an illusion to think that $\mathcal{Z}=\mathcal{Z}[J=0]$ depends on a genuine variable $\phi_c$; it is essentially just a number.

yeah indeed I don't really get why you have changed that, since $\frac{δ\Gamma}{δ\phi_{J}}=-J$ vanish only at $J=0$... so I would say that the minima is really the vev without any source

Well, it can be argued based on the definition of the Legendre transform. I might have misunderstood your notation, though, so feel free to edit.
