# Calculating generating functional with stationary phase approximation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral, correlation-functions, partition-function

Let's say that I have a generating functional $Z[J]$ defined as:
\begin{equation*}
Z[J]=\int \mathcal{D}\phi\,e^{iS[\phi]+i\int d^4x\,J\phi}.\tag{1}
\end{equation*}
I want to use the stationary phase approximation, but it gives this (using $\frac{\delta S}{\delta \phi}+J=0$):
\begin{equation*}
Z[J]=e^{iS_\text{cl.}[\phi]}e^{iF\left[ \frac{-i\delta}{\delta J} \right]}\int\mathcal{D}\Delta\phi\,e^{\frac{i}{2}\int d^4x \int d^4y \left. \frac{\delta^2\mathcal{L}}{\delta \phi(x)\delta\phi(y)}\right|_{\phi_\text{cl.}}\Delta\phi(x)\Delta\phi(y)}e^{i\int d^4x\,J\phi_\text{cl.}},\tag{2}
\end{equation*}
where $F$ contains all the terms of order $\geq 3$ in $\Delta\phi$. But this expression induces that:
\begin{equation*}
Z[J]=e^{iS_\text{cl.}[\phi]}e^{iF\left[ \phi_\text{cl.}\right]}\int\mathcal{D}\Delta\phi\,e^{\frac{i}{2}\int d^4x \int d^4y \left. \frac{\delta^2\mathcal{L}}{\delta \phi(x)\delta\phi(y)}\right|_{\phi_\text{cl.}}\Delta\phi(x)\Delta\phi(y)}e^{i\int d^4x\,J\phi_\text{cl.}}.\tag{3}
\end{equation*}
So an expectation value like $\langle \phi \rangle$ may be written as:
$$\begin{align*}
\langle \phi \rangle&=\left. \frac{-i\delta}{\delta J} \frac{Z[J]}{Z[0]} \right|_{J=0}
\\
&=\phi_\text{cl.}
\end{align*}\tag{4}$$
This seems OK but for me, it is problematic because this result does not depend on the approximation we choose for $F$ (the order in $\Delta\phi$ at which $F$ ends). Is this normal or my calculations are wrong or there's a way to make this result dependant on the approximation? (should I really expand the action around the solution with a source?)

Comment: How did the $J\phi$ term in eq. (1) become $J\phi_{\rm cl}$ in eq. (2)?

Comment: @Qmechanic Since $J\phi=J\phi_\text{cl.}+J\Delta\phi$, $J\Delta\phi$ is absorbed by the classical equation of motion $\frac{\delta S}{\delta \phi}\Delta\phi+J\Delta\phi$ when expanding the action around the classical solution. Then the only term surviving this is $J\phi_\text{cl.}$.

Answer (score 2):

1. The first equality in OP's eq. (4) is a general result in Fourier theory that doesn't depend on the stationary phase/WKB approximation.
2. The second equality in OP's eq. (4) is proven in my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/348518/2451). Be aware that $\phi_{\rm cl}$ often denotes the Legendre-transformed variable in the [effective action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_action) $\Gamma[\phi_{\rm cl}]$, as opposed to a classical solution of the [Euler-Lagrange (EL) equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation). (OP is talking about the latter). The 2 notions agree to ${\cal O}(\hbar)$, i.e. not necessarily at quantum-level.

Answer (score 0):

If we take as you say that $\phi_{cl}$ is a saddle-point and therefore satisfies
$$\frac{\delta S}{\delta \phi}\bigg|_{\phi_{cl}} + J = 0$$ for a given $J$, then the first order term is canceled completely on OP's equation (3), that is, no term $e^{i\int J\phi_{cl}}$ should be present.

While on the contrary all the terms in $F$ still depend on the fluctuations $\Delta \phi$ so they cannot be taken out of the path integral. That is where you lose higher order terms. These are generally vanishing in one-loop approximations, but you can see for example if the interaction where $\phi^3$ or anything of higher order that these terms will generate terms which are being neglected, let us make $\phi\rightarrow \phi_{cl} + \Delta\phi$
$$\phi^3 \rightarrow \phi_{cl}^3 + 3\phi_{cl}\Delta\phi + 3\Delta\phi^2\phi_{cl} + \Delta\phi^3$$
So this sort of terms might appear in the Lagrangian and you are taking them out in your Eq.(3). There is no freedom on $F$ as you seem to believe, there is just a truncation up to a certain order and that completely specifies what $F$ is and what one is neglecting (if you want to keep the path integral Gaussian)

Comment: So, in order to have $Z[J]$ that still depends on $J$, I have to take a $\phi_\text{cl.}$ that satisfies the free equation of motion $\frac{\delta S}{\delta \phi}=0$?

Comment: Depends on what you are looking into... I guess. If you want only to approximate $Z[J]$, the saddle point corresponds to the EOM above. And you still have $Z[J]$ where $J$ appears in higher orders together with the fluctuations.  $\Delta \phi$.

Comment: Why will $Z[J]$ still depend on $J$ if $e^{i\int J\phi_\text{cl.}}$ disappear, as you said?

Comment: But with those terms, in the expansion of the action I have terms like $\left(\left.\frac{\delta S}{\delta\phi}\right|_{\phi_\text{cl.}}+J\right)\Delta\phi$, and this gives $0$.

Comment: True, the one that stays is indeed $J\phi_{cl}$, so that is already a $J$ dependence, but you will still have higher order terms in $F$. I will expand the answer