# Functional derivative of the generating functional with respect to the source term

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral, correlation-functions, functional-derivatives, 1pi-effective-action

To be specific, let us use the notations in W. Metzner et al., Rev. Mod. Phys. 84,299 (2012).
The generating functional $G[\eta, \bar\eta]$ is given by [Eq. 4]
\begin{align}
G[\eta, \bar\eta] = - \ln \int D\psi D\bar\psi e^{-S[\psi,\bar\psi]} e^{(\bar\eta,\psi)+(\bar\psi,\eta)}.
\end{align}

I want to know what is the functional derivative $\partial G /\partial \eta$?  I have two guesses.

First,
Below Eq. 9, the authors showed that
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial G }{ \partial \eta} = \bar\psi
\end{align}
and in Eq. 19 the authors have used a trick where $V[\psi,\bar\psi]$
is replaced by $V[\partial_{\bar\eta}, \partial_{\eta}]$.
This clearly shows that the functional derivative of the generating functional $G[\eta,\bar\eta]$ with respect to the source field $\eta$ is the conjugate field $\bar\psi$.

My second guess is that
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial{G}}{\partial \eta} = 
-\frac{\int D\psi D\bar\psi [-\bar\psi] e^{-S[\psi,\bar\psi]}e^{(\bar\eta,\psi)+(\bar\psi, \eta)}}{\int D\psi D\bar\psi e^{-S[\psi,\bar\psi]}e^{(\bar\eta,\psi)+(\bar\psi, \eta)}}.
\end{align}
This is the expectation value of the field operator with finit source.
In the zero souce case, this gives the expectation value
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial{G}}{\partial \eta}\Big{|}_{\eta = \bar\eta = 0} = 
-\frac{\int D\psi D\bar\psi [-\bar\psi] e^{-S[\psi,\bar\psi]}}{\int D\psi D\bar\psi e^{-S[\psi,\bar\psi]}}
= \langle \bar\psi \rangle
\end{align}
By taking the second-order derivative, we have
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial^2{G}}{\partial\bar\eta\partial \eta}\Big{|}_{\eta = \bar\eta = 0} 
= -\langle \bar\psi \rangle \langle \psi \rangle + \langle \psi \bar\psi \rangle
= \langle \psi \bar\psi \rangle_{c}
\end{align}
This coincides with the Eq. 7 with $m = 1$.

I do not know how to reconcile these two cases.

So what is the functional derivative of the generating functional $G[\eta, \bar\eta]$ with respect to the source field $\eta$? Is it the conjugate field $\bar\psi$
or its expectation value $\langle \bar\psi\rangle$ with finit source?

Comment: It's always an expectation value.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functional derivative $$\frac{\delta W_c[J]}{\delta J_k}$$
of the generating functional of connected diagrams $W_c[J]$ wrt. a sources $J_k$ is both

1. the [classical field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_action) $\phi_{\rm cl}^k$ and
2. the expectation value $\langle \phi^k \rangle_J$

(up to sign conventions in the case of a Grassmann-odd field), cf. e.g. eq. (4) in my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/348518/2451).

Confusingly, Ref. 1 uses the same notation for a field and its classical field, which likely caused OP's question.

References:

1. W. Metzner, M. Salmhofer, C. Honerkamp, V. Meden & K. Schönhammer, [Rev. Mod. Phys. 84 (2012) 299](https://doi.org/10.1103/RevModPhys.84.299).

Comment: Thank you very much.