# In QFT, is the effective potential at tree-level always the same as the potential? Why?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, potential, 1pi-effective-action

If I have a simple scalar theory

$$ \mathcal{L}(\phi) = \frac{1}{2} (\partial_\mu \phi)^2 - V(\phi), $$

the effective potential $V_{eff}$, derived from $Z\rightarrow W \rightarrow \Gamma \rightarrow V_{eff}$, has at tree-level precisely the same formula of the potential $V(\phi)$. I guess this makes sense, or they would've chosen a different name.

I can't find an answer to the question: is this always the case, at tree-level? Why or why not? If so, is there a motivation/intuition for this?

Addendum: the [question linked in the comment](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/337898/in-what-sense-is-the-proper-effective-action-gamma-phi-c-a-quantum-correcte) only partially answers my questions. I don't understand where the kinetic term goes, nor how the integral in $S=\int\mathcal{L}$ does not play any role.

Comment: This is essentially as duplicate of [In what sense is the proper/effective action $\Gamma[\phi_c]$ a quantum-corrected classical action $S[\phi]$?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/337898/2451)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OP's sought-for formula
$${\cal V}_\text{eff,tree-level}(\phi_{\rm cl})~=~{\cal V}(\phi_{\rm cl})$$
follows from the following facts:

1. Ref. 1 defines the *effective potential* ${\cal V}_{\rm eff}(\phi_{\rm cl})$ for $x$-independent field configurations $\phi_{\rm cl}$ only. Then the kinetic terms don't contribute. Ref. 1 then writes the [effective action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_action) as
   $$ \Gamma[\phi_{\rm cl}]~=~-(VT){\cal V}_{\rm eff}(\phi_{\rm cl}), \tag{11.50}$$
   where $VT$ is the 4-volume of spacetime.
2. Similarly, for $x$-independent field configurations $\phi$, we can write the action
   $$ S[\phi]~=~-(VT){\cal V}(\phi)$$
   with the help of the potential ${\cal V}(\phi)$.
3. Finally use the fact that
   $$ \Gamma_\text{tree-level}[\phi_{\rm cl}]~=~S[\phi_{\rm cl}], $$
   cf. e.g. eq. (12) in my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/348518/2451). $\Box$

References:

1. M.E. Peskin & D.V. Schroeder, *An Intro to QFT,* 1995; eq. (11.50).